# Работа с API с помощью SQL

Tags: sql, http, oracle, api

Передо мной поставили задачу:

1. Нужно отправить запрос на адрес onlyoffice.eu/api/2.0/authentication с параметрами `username` и `password`.
2. Получить в ответе от сервера `token`.
3. При INSERT'e в таблицу автоматически отправлять свежедобавленные строки (`lastname`, `firstname`, `email` из таблицы `USERS`) на https://onlyoffice.eu/api/2.0/people, при этом добавив в `Header` `token` из предыдущего запроса.

При этом всё это делается в Oracle.
Погуглив, я понял, что выполнить это можно с помощью UTL_HTTP, но разобраться с ним так и не смог. А третий пункт - это нужно создать триггер, который вызовет метод с отправкой файлов.

Погуглил, попробовал несколько решений, но ни одно не подошло. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать этот запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure publish_cinema_even
is
  req utl_http.req;
  res utl_http.resp;
  url varchar2(4000) := 'https://alsytto.onlyoffice.eu/api/2.0/authentication.xml?userName=email@mail.ru&password=password';
  name varchar2(4000);
  buffer varchar2(4000); 
  content varchar2(4000) := '{}';

begin
  utl_http.set_wallet ('file:c:\app\wallet2','test1234');
  utl_http.set_detailed_excp_support (true);
  req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');

  --UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:/c:\app\oraUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\BIN\wallets', 'test1234');
  --utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
  --utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json'); 
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content));

  utl_http.write_text(req, content);
  res := utl_http.get_response(req);
  -- process the response from the HTTP call
  begin 
    loop
      utl_http.read_line(res, buffer);
      dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
    end loop;
    utl_http.end_response(res);
  exception
    when utl_http.end_of_body 
    then
      utl_http.end_response(res);
  end;
end publish_cinema_even;
```